# Alternative to PerformanceCounter for Linux Container

Tags: c#, docker

I'm trying to migrate a log file clean up service written in C# to Azure, and part of this migration is getting the service to run within a Docker container.

The service runs as expected outside of the container. However, when ran inside a container, this error is thrown:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Performance Counters are not supported on this platform.
```

Having looked online I can see that `PerformanceCounter` is only available for windows.

I have not yet been able to find a viable alternative and so am asking here. I need something which can replace this current function.

```
public static float PercentFreeOnDisk(string letter, string machine)
    {
        using (var perfCounter = new PerformanceCounter("LogicalDisk", "% Free Space", letter, machine))
            return perfCounter.NextValue();
    }
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, there won't be drive letters within a Linux container either, so that'll take some changing too.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/blob/main/src/TelemetryConsumers/Orleans.TelemetryConsumers.Linux/LinuxEnvironmentStatistics.cs